# Restore mis-uninstall applications

Tags: windows, windows-10

I wanted to uninstall an application in my computer and I used the default uninstall tool. Unfortunately I chose the wrong application. So, I’m afraid I uninstalled some system application (e.g. Bluetooth driver).

Where can I find the history of application uninstallation in my computer, or the default system applications list in my computer. I know this list may varied in different computer model.

My computer model: Dell latitude 7390, Windows

Comment: You could check your EventLog but it can be quite hard to read.

Comment: @Seth I have tried it but I can’t see which event is an uninstallation.

Comment: Most installers do not log anything, except Windows Installer. I’m afraid you’re most likely out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Event log>Windows log>Application.

Then you could find the date/time and source option.

Date/time option : You could find the time to uninstall it.

Source option : You could find the Msinstaller.

[image]

Comment: @Minghui Ouyang If you did uninstall something important and you don't have the installer for it you may be able to do a system restore to the point before you did the uninstall.